# PHP5 getting page for all categories

Tags: php

So this question comes from another i created you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279968/php5-unique-data-page-for-specific-items) But i have changed my code so now it looks something like this:

**Car Controller**

```
public function indexAction(){

        $category = new Application_Model_CarMapper();
        $gcat = $this->getRequest()->getPathInfo();

        //get id

        $id = $category->find_id_by_name($gcat); 

        $this->view->title = $category->get_sub_cat_select($id);
    }
```

This is a new function i created inside the mapper:

```
public function find_id_by_name($name){

        $select = $this->getDbTable()->query("SELECT * FROM car_category WHERE category_name = '{$name}'");
        $result = $select->fetchAll();

        if(!$result) {
            return;
        }   
        return $result[0]['ID'];
    }
```

I am testing it out by the title but it just doesnt seem to display at all. I would like it to display the drop down menus for the specific category, e.g

car-live.local/cars/Volvo ---> "Welcome to the **Volvo** Car Finder"

car-live.local/cars/BMW ---> "Welcome to the **BMW** Car Finder"

I know it is not working as i have to split down the URL even more, as right now it is finding the id via the URL, but i am unsure how to do this :s Any light you can shed on this would be extremely grateful.. Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

New code:

```
public function indexAction(){

        $category = new Application_Model_CarMapper();
        $gcat = explode("/", $this->getRequest()->getPathInfo());

        if(isset($gcat['category_name'])) {

        $id = $category->find_id_by_name($gcat); 

        $this->view->title = $category->get_sub_cat_select($id);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't need `{$name}` as you are not using `array[index]`

Comment: So how would i adapt that in the current code? Plus, it is the `indexAction` i am looking to change rather than the query itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly your issue, but from code it seems like you're having issues dealing with the URL. So, let's take this example:

`car-live.local/car/Volvo`

After you get at `indexAction` you should [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) by the `/`.

This is return an array with all the components of the URL, then you take the last one in this case would be `Volvo` and send it to your `find_id_by_name()` method.

My usual approach to this problems is to follow something like:

1. Explode by slashes;
2. Get the first one (in this case `car` and "route" it to a cars class, by sending to the constructor that and the rest of the request;
3. The `car` class constructor then takes the next part of the URL `Volvo` and "routes" it an appropriate method like `getVolvo()` or whatever you need...

You can route it to what you need, but just try to delegate the responsibilities of processing the URL to the appropriate classes. Example:

`/cars/whatEverCar` => Should be processed by class `car`

`/bike/whatEverBike` => Should be processed by class `bike`

Hope this helps.

---

Edit:

Your `find_id_by_name()` method can have some URL like:

`/car/find_id_by_name/Volvo`

Am I explaining this well? You can take parts of the URL and call methods directly... and send the rest of the URL.

---

**Edit 2:** Code example...

The following code is a very nice solution for your problem:

```
<?php
// Call this class as soon the site stars
class Router {

    public function __construct() {
        // In some really cool way get your full URL, for example I'm gonna use a string...
        $fullURL = "example.com/Car/findCarById/Volvo";

        array_shift($fullURL); // removes "example.com", obvious stuff...

        $explodedUrl = explode("/", $fullURL);

        $targetClass = $explodedUrl[0]; // Temporary store the target is "Car"
        array_shift($fullURL); // Removes "Car", we don't need it anymore...

        $target = new $targetClass($fullURL); // call the Car class responsible for handling all the "Car" related stuff!
    }
}

class Car {

    public function __construct($request) {
        // $request is an array with "findCarById", "Volvo"
        $targetMethod = $request[0]; // Temporary store the target is "findCarById"
        array_shift($request);
        $this->$targetMethod($request);
    }

    private function findCarById($parameter) {
        // $parameter is an array with "Volvo"..
        // Now to your query and other cool stuff with $parameter[0];
        print "I'm the method findCarById() of the class Car called by the main router to find the ID for {$parameter}...";
    }
}

?>
```

If you need to add more functions to your `Car` class, just add another method and then call it over the URL with his name, same way I did with `findCarById()`.

Warning: This code might have minor bugs, it was written on Notepad and IS NOT tested.

Comment: Thank you.. @TCB13: well you are making some sort of sense, i understand the bit about exploding the URL but then everything just gets confusing after that.. Also as there are many categories i dont see making a seperate class and getfunction for each type of car.. plus this is not how the client wants it structured as he would like it done on his terms.. Well i have edited the code which can now be seen in the above edit so if you can show where to go from there, i will be very grateful? :)

Comment: @ash like I told you on the edit, just create a `car` class with the `find_id_by_name()` method and route it over the URL as I explained. MainRouter (gets /car/) builds the class `car` and send over /find_id_by_name/Volvo/ then the constructor calls the method find_id_by_name() from the URL and passes the /Volvo part.

Comment: oohh, the technical terms threw me.. Maybe an example may help or step by step?

Comment: @ash check my edit. Take your time to think, but I'm sure that's what you really want. Don't forget to accept the answer...

Comment: Thanks.. i will change my code around and update you with the outcome :)